# How can i copy certain parts of an array to another in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

So what my program should do is: Read a .txt file with this piece of code.

```
FILE *fp;
char filename[40],part1[4],part2[4]; 
int c=0,pt1,pt2; 
printf("\nEnter a file name to open: ");
gets(filename); 
if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r"))!= NULL) 
{
    printf("\nThe file %s was opened successfully!",filename);  
}
else
{
    printf("\nThe file didnt open succesfully!");
}
```

And then store each line in the `row` string like this.

```
fgets(part1,4,fp); 
pt1 = atoi(part1); 
struct input 
{
    char name[20],row[30],code[3],nPieces[3],needed[3],usage[3],nUses[3];
};

struct input list[pt1];  

while (c++ < pt1 )  
{
    fgets(list[c].row,30,fp); 
    printf ("\n%s", list[c].row);
}
```

But the problem is that after that i must take the row string and cut it into pieces (for exp the 1st line of txt was <1 Glass 2 0 9 3 1> where each number represents something) So what i want is to put the "1" into the code[3] string the "Glass" into the name[30] string etc. I tried to make it work using the `isspace()` scaning the row string and whenever it found a space it would copy the row array from 0-(the space - 1) using `strncpy()`. For some reason when ever i run tha program is stops working. Anyone that could suggest anything?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to allocate an array of size pt1, but that won't work because this is compile time and the value of pt1 is not known.

With:

```
struct input 
{
    char name[20],row[30],code[3],nPieces[3],needed[3],usage[3],nUses[3];
};
```

you declare a *variable*, but it seems you want to define a type, so:

```
typedef struct input 
{
    char name[20],row[30],code[3],nPieces[3],needed[3],usage[3],nUses[3];
};
```

and then later you must malloc the memory:

```
struct input list= calloc(pt1, sizeof(struct input));
```

The statement

```
struct input list[pt1];
```

should give a compiler error (does with my compiler).

Answer (score 0):

> So what i want is to put the "1" into the code[3] string the "Glass"
>   into the name[30] string etc.

It's much easier with `sscanf()` rather than `isspace()` and `strncpy()`:

```
    sscanf(list[c].row, "%2s%19s%2s%2s%2s%2s",
                        list[c].code,
                        list[c].name, list[c].nPieces, list[c].needed, list[c].usage,
                                                                       list[c].nUses)
```